# Why do the items in the recycler View are not showing well Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

So I made my list so it look like this :

[image]

but I don't know for what ever reason it show like that:

[image]

Here is the frament_drivers.xml that hold the RecycleView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/calendar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/marianneb"
                android:text="Pilotes"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/drivers_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/driver_list"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the driver_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50px"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"

    android:background="@drawable/rectangle">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/driver_position"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/marianneb"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/driver_bar"
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ferrari_bar"/>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/driver_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/marianneb"
            android:text="Charles Leclerc"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/driver_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mariannem"
                android:text="16"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/driver_team"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/mariannem"
                android:text="Ferrari"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/driver_points"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/marianneb"
        android:text="578"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Then I have the DriversFragment.kt:

```
package net.robcorp.finalapp

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Insets.add
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.view.OneShotPreDrawListener.add
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import net.robcorp.finalapp.R
import net.robcorp.finalapp.databinding.FragmentDriversBinding
import net.robcorp.finalapp.drivers.DriverFragmentAdapter
import net.robcorp.finalapp.drivers.Drivers
import org.json.JSONArray


class DriversFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_drivers) {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var myAdapter: DriverFragmentAdapter;
    lateinit var binding: FragmentDriversBinding
    private val drivers = ArrayList<Drivers>()
    val url = "https://robcorp.net/f1api/getdrivers.php"

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentDriversBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        recyclerView = binding.driversRecyclerView
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        myAdapter = DriverFragmentAdapter(drivers)
        recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
        println("adapter loaded")
        downloadDrivers()
    }

    fun downloadDrivers() {
        val task = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context)
        val request = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, {
                response ->
            val data = response.toString()
            val jArray = JSONArray(data)
//            Log.e("Error",response.toString())
            for (i in 0..jArray.length()-1) {
                val json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i)
//                Log.e("Jobject",json_data.toString())
                val pos = i+1
                val name = json_data.getString("Name")
                val nb = json_data.getString("NB")
                val points = json_data.getString("Points")
                val title = json_data.getString("Title")
                val driver = Drivers(pos, name, nb, points, title)
                drivers.add(driver)

            }
            println(drivers)
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }, {
                error ->
            println(error)
        })
        task.add(request)
    }
}
```

And finally I have the DriverFragmentAdapter.kt

```
package net.robcorp.finalapp.drivers

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import net.robcorp.finalapp.R
import net.robcorp.finalapp.databinding.DriverListBinding

class DriverFragmentAdapter(private var driversList: List<Drivers>): RecyclerView.Adapter<DriverFragmentAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    class MyViewHolder(val binding: DriverListBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(driver: Drivers) {
            val context = itemView.context
            val pos = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.driver_position)
            val bar = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.driver_bar)
            val name = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.driver_name)
            val nb = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.driver_number)
            val team = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.driver_team)
            val points = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.driver_points)

            pos.text = driver.pos.toString()
            name.text = driver.name
            nb.text = driver.nb
            team.text = driver.title
            points.text = driver.points

            if (driver.title == "Ferrari") {
                bar.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ferrari_bar)
            } else if (driver.title == "Alpine") {
                bar.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.alpine_bar)
            } else if (driver.title == "Red Bull") {
                bar.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.redbull_bar)
            } else if (driver.title == "Mercedes") {
                bar.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.mercedes_bar)
            } else if (driver.title == "McLaren") {
                bar.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.mclaren_bar)
            } else if (driver.title == "Alfa Romeo") {
                bar.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.alfaromeo_bar)
            } else if (driver.title == "AlphaTauri") {
                bar.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.alphatauri_bar)
            } else if (driver.title == "Williams") {
                bar.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.williams_bar)
            } else if (driver.title == "Aston Martin") {
                bar.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.astonmartin_bar)
            } else if (driver.title == "Haas") {
                bar.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.haas_bar)
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(DriverListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)))

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return driversList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val driver = driversList[position]
        holder.binding.apply {
            holder.bind(driver)
        }
    }

    fun setDriversList(driversList: List<Drivers>) {
        this.driversList = driversList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

I can't manage to find why it's showing like that

Comment: use Item Decoration https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration

Answer (score 0):

Try adding start/end constraints to the recyclerView item like this

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/drivers_recycler_view"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                tools:listitem="@layout/driver_list"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Also you must remove the '+' sign when constraining to another object

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
```

It should be

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
```

Comment: It didn't change anything But for the moment I used cards and they are centered but because of the elevation I got some weird black lines

Comment: You can change the elevation on the cards. Try reading this <https://material.io/components/cards>. I usually follow this guides and use the snippets from here

Answer (score 0):

Give `paddingStart` and `paddingEnd` 20dp to `RecyclerView`.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drivers_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
        tools:listitem="@layout/driver_list" />
```

and change this to item `main layout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"

    android:background="@drawable/rectangle">
```

**Hope this will work.**

Comment: what do you mean by changing to main Layout?

Comment: driver_list.xml first layout.

Comment: isn't it first Layout already? And with the pading it's making a weird thing with elevation

Comment: Mainly there is issues with driver_list.xml by padding and margin of First Linear layout. Check that first.

Comment: I've tried changing paddings and margins but nothing happened so I added a card view arround it and it works

Comment: Okk That's great.

Answer (score 0):

Add all constraints to your `recyclerView`

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
```

remove plus sign from your constraint

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drivers_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header" />
```

By changing the numbers in this code you swap spaces from above and below

```
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
```

These codes let you leave how much space left and right

```
android:paddingStart="16dp"
android:paddingEnd="16dp"
```

driverlist.xml

add to outermost linear layout

```
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
```

Comment: That just add a padding at the beginning and at the end of the Recycler View and won't make a space between items

Comment: what do you want exactly, can you try the code I wrote and post a screenshot bro, how does it not work?

Comment: there isn't a space between the posts. I've manage to make something work

Comment: I added a new code, add it to driverlist.xml I guess your problem will be solved now

Answer (score 0):

I've manage a sotlution that is to add a cardview and put my layout inside

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).